# max length to hibernate column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I create table using hibernate through entity.

How to set length of an column in hibernate with maximum length.

for example :

```
@Column(name="txn_details_id",nullable = false)
private String txnId;
```

if  I use the above it will create with the `default size : 255` but i want to create this column with the maximum allowed size.

how do i do this in hibernate?

It would be helpful if some one helps me to set the max length for all the types.

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do like this

size only

```
@Column(name="txn_details_id",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "varchar(50)")
private String txnId;
```

Or

size with default value

```
@Column(name="txn_details_id",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "varchar(50) default 'ACTIVE'")
private String txnId;
```

Comment: thanks it helped to solve my issues `@Column(name="txn_details_id",nullable = false,columnDefinition = "varchar(max)")
 private String txnId;`